# Check for null List from Rest endpoint

Tags: java

I receive this DTO in Spring Rest Endpoint:

```
public class RequestDTO {
    private List<Integer> additionalImages;
}
```

I want check the list and do some iterations if it's not null:

```
    List<Integer> additionalImages = dto.getAdditionalImages();

    if(additionalImages != null || !additionalImages.isEmpty())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < additionalImages.size(); i++){
            ProductImages pi = new ProductImages();
            pi.setProductId(result.getId());
            pi.setAdditionalImages(i);
            productImagesService.save(pi);
        }
    }
```

What is the proper way to do this check? I get NPE here `additionalImages.size()`.

Comment: I don't see how you could get a NPE at `additionalImages.size()`, you've already null checked. I guess the `!additionalImages.isEmpty()` check is redundant.

Comment: If the response can be null, I suggest `Optional<List<Integer>>`

Comment: What's the concrete `List` implementation type returning from  `dto.getAdditionalImages()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Streams` to iterate over the list and create required objects. It's better to create all `ProductImage` first and then save them all at once.

```
public void foo() {
    List<ProductImage> productImages = createProductImages(dto.getAdditionalImages());
    productImagesService.saveAll(productImages);
}

public List<ProductImage> createProductImages(List<Integer> additionalImages) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(additionalImages).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                   .map(i -> {
                       ProductImage productImage = new ProductImage();
                       productImage.setProductId(result.getId);
                       productImage.setAdditionalImage(i);
                       return productImage;
                   }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `additionalImages.isEmpty` is redundant - the for loop will be skipped if the list is empty, so, you can simplify the if statement
2. Checking "not null or not empty" will check both conditions, so the NPE should actually be there, not the size check.

Comment: Can you please show me modified version of the code?

Comment: Simply remove `|| !additionalImages.isEmpty()`